# What is the simplification of this if-statement?

Tags: performance, if-statement, syntax

```
boolean a,b;
if (!(a && b) && (a || b)) || ((a && b) || !(a || b))
```

Does a tool exists to perform these kinds of simplification?

Comment: Resharper would probably simplify it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%21%28a%20%26%26%20b%29%20%26%26%20%28a%20%7C%7C%20b%29%29%20%7C%7C%20%28%28a%20%26%26%20b%29%20%7C%7C%20%21%28a%20%7C%7C%20b%29%29) will simplify expressions

Your expression is a tautology.
Truth table:

```
a | b | (¬(a&&b)&&(a||b))||(a&&b)||¬(a||b)
T | T | T
T | F | T
F | T | T
F | F | T
```

Answer (score 0):

This will always be true : (a || b) || !(a && b)

```
a b || !||
0 0 0   1
0 1 1   0
1 0 1   0
1 1 1   0
```

And you can do the same with &&.

You can let gcc (if you're C/C++) do the dirty work. (I'm not suggesting to write dirty code)